# automate next/prev buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, button

The code below is for viewing images that fly away. But you have to click 'next' or 'prev' buttons for this to happen. I would like it to happen automatically with a timer that stops on each image for about 5 seconds then changes to the next image then begins again without rewinding. (i can del with a rewind function for now but would ultimately like it to be continuous which basically means the each image would have to fly away the return to the rear of the stack.

```
<div id="view">
        <ul id="stack">

            <li><img src="labels/manzonipinotnoir.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="labels/figgepinotnoir.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="labels/marinusbernardusredwine.png" /></li>
            <li><img src="labels/riverbench.png" /></li>


        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="controls">
        <button class="prev"  disabled="disabled">Prev</button>     
        <button class="next" >Next</button>
        <a> Featured Wineries</a>
    </div>




    <script>
    (function($) {

        var y_space = 50,
            z_space = 50;

        var view = $('#view'),
            lis = $('#stack li'),
            prev = $('.controls .prev'),
            next = $('.controls .next'),
            left = $('#rotate_controls .left'),
            centre = $('#rotate_controls .centre'),
            right = $('#rotate_controls .right');

        var z_index = lis.length,
            current_index = 1,
            translate_y = y_space *-1,
            translate_z = z_space *-1;

        lis.each(function() {

            this.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate3d(0px, ' + translate_y + 'px, ' + translate_z + 'px)';
            this.style['-moz-transform'] = 'translate3d(0px, ' + translate_y + 'px, ' + translate_z + 'px)';
            this.style['z-index'] = z_index;

            $(this).data('translate_y', translate_y);
            $(this).data('translate_z', translate_z);

            z_index--;
            translate_y -= y_space;
            translate_z -= z_space;

        });

        next.bind('click', function() {
            if($(this).attr('disabled')) return false;
            lis.each(function() {
                animate_stack(this, y_space, z_space);  
            });
            lis.filter(':nth-child(' + current_index + ')').css('opacity', 0);
            current_index ++;
            check_buttons();
        });

        prev.bind('click', function() {
            if($(this).attr('disabled')) return false;
            lis.each(function() {
                animate_stack(this, -y_space, -z_space);    
            });
            lis.filter(':nth-child(' + (current_index - 1) + ')').css('opacity', 1);
            current_index --;
            check_buttons();    
        });

        $(document).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
            if(deltaY >= 0) {
                next.trigger('click');
            }
            else {
                prev.trigger('click');
            }
        });

        function check_buttons() {
            if(current_index==1) {
                prev.attr('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                prev.attr('disabled', false);
            }

            if(current_index == lis.length) {
                next.attr('disabled', true);                
            }
            else {
                next.attr('disabled', false);
            }
        }





        function animate_stack(obj, y, z) {

            var new_y = $(obj).data('translate_y') + y;
            var new_z = $(obj).data('translate_z') + z;

            obj.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate3d(0px, ' + new_y + 'px, ' + new_z + 'px)';
            obj.style['-moz-transform'] = 'translate3d(0px, ' + new_y + 'px, ' + new_z + 'px)';
            $(obj).data('translate_y', new_y)
            .data('translate_z', new_z);

        }


    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a setInterval method:

```
function timer()
 {
  setInterval(function(){nextImg()},5000);
 }

function nextImg()
{
 // whatever code you have written for next.bind
}
```